# How to set Vuex data without an API call?

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, vuex

I am running a PHP backend and already have the neccesary data that I would like to set within my Vuex store. Normally If I have this data already available and just need it in a component I would simply `html_encode` and `json_encode` this data and pass it along as a prop.

This requires me not to have to make an API call for data that is already available in my view.

Currently I am thinking about doing something like this but this feels ugly because I am working with globals here:

Within my view:

```
<script>
    window.searchContext = {{ $searchContext }};
</script>
```

Then in my `app.js` where my main Vue instance resides:

```
data: {
   searchContext: window.searchContext
}
```

Once I have the data inside my main Vue intance I could fill out my Vuex store. By using something like:

```
created() {
    this.$store.commit('datepicker/arrival', this.searchContext.arrival);
    this.$store.commit('datepicker/arrival', this.searchContext.arrival);
    // etc.
}
```

Would there be a better pattern to do something like this? I could be overthinking this since this might likely work fine though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, what you are currently doing is just fine. It looks ugly but perfectly ok. However, remove this data from the `window` object once it is read.

What you are basically trying to do is **SSR - Server-side rendering**. Once, you start having significant data prerendered, you should switch to official SSR solution.

But doing SSR will need Node.js while you currently have PHP backend. SSR is quite complex in itself and you should choose it only when you need it. It makes build stack complicated.

Read more about [Vue SSR](https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/).